# How can I use SQL and Python together to fill a template file with SQL data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a text file that is a template like this:

```
Question: {QuestionStem}

{answers}

Correct answer: {correctAnswer}
Date: {examDate}
Class: {examClass}
```

I need to populate it and save a copy of it with every question in an exam.

The exam data comes from a T-SQL Query (MSSQL) that looks like this:

```
QuestionID  QuestionStem             QuestionOrder  AnswerId        AnswerText      AnswerOrder     isCorrect  Class        Date
100         What color is the sky?   0              1               Red             0               0          Astronomy    10/1/2024
100         What color is the sky?   0              2               Blue            1               1          Astronomy    10/1/2024
100         What color is the sky?   0              3               Orange          2               0          Astronomy    10/1/2024
100         What color is the sky?   0              4               Green           3               0          Astronomy    10/1/2024
200         The Sun is bright(T/F)   1              11              True            0               1          Astronomy    5/1/2024
200         The Sun is bright(T/F)   1              12              False           1               0          Astronomy    5/1/2024
```

I need the data for each exam to fill the template file like this:

```
Question: What color is the sky?

a. Red 
b. Blue 
c. Orange 
d. Green

Correct answer: b 
Date: 10/1/2024 
Class: Astronomy


Question: The Sun is bright(T/F)

a. True 
b. False

Correct answer: a 
Date: 5/1/2024 
Class: Astronomy
```

Does Python have a way of taking the SQL data, populating the template with the data, and then saving it as a text file?

For Fynn :)

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/kUEf6hZT

The output of your code is wonderful as you can see below...but I can't get the `isCorrect` part to work:

```
Question: What color is the sky?

-[ ] Red
-[ ] Green
-[ ] Gold
-[ ] Blue

Correct answer:
Date: 2023-08-23
Class: Astro 101
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Perform the SQL query, loop through the results, and use f-strings to format the data that you write to the file. It should be 10-20 lines of code at most.

Comment: It does, however, seem like your table could do with some normalisation.

Comment: On a **supported** version of SQL Server this would be quite easily achieved with string aggregation as well.

Comment: @ThomA you mean I could do this with only SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, with with aggregation. But `STRING_AGG` is your friend for that. You're using a completely unsupported version which doesn't have access to `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: use polars or pandas , very clean and useful

Comment: @AshkanGolehPour I thought `pandas` was for dealing with Excel files?

Comment: @ThomA I just looked into `STRING_AGG`...I don't see anything about using it with a template?  thanks

Comment: The documentation isn't gongm to have a solution to your specific problem, @SkyeBoniwell ; it's the role of the developer (you) to work out how to use the tools at your disposal.

Comment: Here's an overly generous start for you: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8S1G_Hwu) It's flawed (on answer IDs) but it certainly shows you that it's not that hard purely in T-SQL.

Comment: @ThomA thank you! I really appreciate you taking the time and effort to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the T-SQL results directly from Python you can check out [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mssql.html), but this depends on specifics of your setup, so I just assume that you can get this query output into a string somehow.

What you can do is of course just using fstrings, but if this project get's a little more involved, or you want to be able to separate the template from the code, you should use Pythons [Template](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/string.html#string.Template) class.
A more involved, but also more capable alternative is a full fledged templating engine like [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/).

I wrote some sample code, that takes the query output as a string and subtstitutes it into a template.
This could have been done with a little less involvement, but by using dataclasses we can keep everything nice and tidy.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from dataclasses import dataclass
from operator import attrgetter
from string import Template

# define the template string
# this could come from a file etc.
_TEMPLATE = Template("""
Question: ${question_stem}

${options}

Correct answer: ${correct_answer}
Date: ${exam_date}
Class: ${exam_class}
""")


# define helper classes to do the work
@dataclass
class Answer:
    order: str
    text: str
    correct: bool

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


@dataclass
class Question:
    order: str
    text: str
    options: list[Answer]

    def __str__(self):
        # ensure correct order of options
        self.options.sort(key=attrgetter('order'))
        # supports multiple correct answers
        correct_answer = ", ".join([
            str(answer)
            for answer
            in self.options
            if answer.correct
        ])

        # substitute only the known values
        return _TEMPLATE.safe_substitute({
            'question_stem': self.text,
            'options': "\n".join([f'-[ ] {option}' for option in self.options]),
            'correct_answer': correct_answer,
        })


@dataclass
class Exam:
    klass: str
    date: str
    questions: list[Question]

    def __str__(self):
        # ensure correct order of options
        self.questions.sort(key=attrgetter('order'))
        return Template("\n".join([
            str(question)
            for question
            in self.questions
        ])).substitute({
            'exam_class': self.klass,
            'exam_date': self.date
        }).strip()

    @classmethod
    def from_data(cls, data: list[list[str]]) -> list['Exam']:
        # nested dict with klass -> question -> answer
        exams = defaultdict(dict)

        # loop over rows
        for (question_id, question_stem, question_order,
             answer_id, answer_text, answer_order, is_correct,
             klass, date) in data:

            # one answer per row
            answer = Answer(answer_order, answer_text, True if is_correct == "1" else False)

            question = exams[(klass, date)].get(question_id)
            if question is not None:
                question.options.append(answer)
            else:
                question = Question(question_order, question_stem, [answer])
                exams[(klass, date)][question_id] = question

        return [cls(klass, date,
                    [question
                     for question
                     in questions.values()])
                for (klass, date), questions
                in exams.items()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # your toy data, representing rows from a database query
    query_result = """
    QuestionID  QuestionStem             QuestionOrder  AnswerId        AnswerText      AnswerOrder     isCorrect  Class        Date
    100         What color is the sky?   0              1               Red             0               0          Astronomy    10/1/2024
    100         What color is the sky?   0              2               Blue            1               1          Astronomy    10/1/2024
    100         What color is the sky?   0              3               Orange          2               0          Astronomy    10/1/2024
    100         What color is the sky?   0              4               Green           3               0          Astronomy    10/1/2024
    200         The Sun is bright(T/F)   1              11              True            0               1          Astronomy    5/1/2024
    200         The Sun is bright(T/F)   1              12              False           1               0          Astronomy    5/1/2024
    """

    # clean this up a bit
    rows = [[field.strip() for field in line.split('  ') if field] for line in query_result.splitlines()[2:-1]]

    for exam in Exam.from_data(rows):
        print(exam)
```

Obviously you would have to run this with real data and tweak the cleanup, also, maybe play around with the template string, and put it into an extra file, etc. And if you go down the SQLAlchemy road, you probably want to hook those classes up to the ORM as well.

### Follow up:

Using pandas is much nicer than plain lists anyway.
I would guess, that pandas gets the data "as is", and not as strings, so the check `is_correct == "1"` fails, because `1 != "1"`.

Try with this instead:

```py
answer = Answer(answer_order, answer_text, bool(is_correct))
```

**If this doesn't work**, please update the pastebin link with **only** the output of `print(df.to_json())`, because that enables me to see what's actually inside your dataframe.

If my assumption is correct though, this should work.
That is, because the integer zero is falsy, and the integer 1 is truthy.
Be aware, that every int that isn't zero is truthy, e.g. -1.
This is unexpected for some people, and could ruin your day if you get different data in there.
The `bool` is not even strictly necessary, but we're advertising a certain type, so we should actually convert to that.

Comment: Hi! I almost got this to work!  But the `isCorrect` part doesn't work.   I have everything else working.  My data does have the `isCorrect` data with 0s and 1s, but nothing shows up for correct answer.

Comment: Hey @SkyeBoniwell, the problem is probably in the following line `answer = Answer(answer_order, answer_text, True if is_correct == "1" else False)`, in the `Exam.from_data` method. If you step through it with a debugger (or print the contents of `is_correct`), then you can see how to amend the ternary clause (with the `if`).

Otherwise, if that doesn't work, could you paste your code, and the input file e.g. to https://pastebin.com/? If you need to obfuscate the data, do it, but "this part doesn't work" is not much to go on =(

Comment: Hi!  Thanks! I added a link to the pastebin.  I only changed like one line of your amazing code at the very bottom so I just included that and I included sample data.

Comment: When I step through the code, I see that it recognizes the `isCorrect` as being 1 or 0, but when it gets to the `Question` class it will say `correct=False` for every answer even if `isCorrect` is 1.

Comment: oops Fynn! I added the Pastebin.com link at the bottom of my question... :)

Comment: I'm sorry, one more bit of info....my data doesn't include the `headers` in Python because I can't figure out how to get a pandas dataframe to turn into a list with headers.   But it still seems to work, it's just that the `isCorrect` feature doesn't work. I added your codes output in my question just so you can see what it does.

Comment: Hey @SkyeBoniwell no worries. I'll put my reply at the end of the answer, because it allows for better formatting